# Can Chrome Show the Original Traceback While Using Source Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, coffeescript, web-inspector, source-maps

When using source maps to allow debugging CoffeeScript code in Chrome, it would be useful sometimes to be able to see the errors in the compiled JS, as you would if you weren't using source mapping.

Is there a way to tell Chrome to display the original traceback?

Comment: have you tried taking your shirt off?

Comment: Tried to find a picture of TJ H with no shirt but had to settle for jash :(